# Add DLL to ASP.NET vNext Project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

My goal is to add a reference of my ASP.NET vNext to the old MySql.Data.dll. I think that this should be possible.

I put it in a NuGet package but if I compiled my project, I receive an error message. 
Anything there is wrong. 
Is there a guideline anywhere showing how to add DLL references? I searched a lot until now, but haven't had found anything.

Comment: "I became a error message" - What does the error say?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29494695/add-assemblies-to-visual-studio-2015-asp-net-5

Answer (score 3):

I assume this is same question as the post below? If you still have questions please do let us know.
http://forums.asp.net/t/1998097.aspx?Add+NET+4+5+Assembly+As+Reference+

Answer (score -1):

One workaround is to create a class library project with your library reference. Then use a project reference from your website to the class library project.