# Add Assemblies to Visual Studio 2015 ASP.NET 5

Tags: assemblies, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to add "Stimulsoft.Report.dll" as an assembly in my Visual Studio 2015 ASP.Net 5 project.

But the reference manager does not contain the assemblies section with the extentions area(as it is in VS 2013), where i could select "Stimulsoft.Report" and add this to my references.

Is there any solution adding these reference to my ASP.NET 5 project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can add the assembly if it available in GAC like below code

```
 "frameworks": {
    "aspnet50": {
        "frameworkAssemblies": {
            "Stimulsoft.Report": ""
        }
    }
}
```

in the second part, you can give the version and type of the assembly

Answer (score 3):

In your `project.json` you can do:

```
"frameworks": {
    "aspnet50": {
        "bin": {
            "assembly": "<path to dll>",
            "pdb": "<path to pdb if needed>"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried adding dll like this and then have this error: http://s29.postimg.org/drr238r7b/Capture.jpg
any help?

Answer (score 3):

One workaround is to create a class library project with your 3rd party library reference.  Then use a project reference from your website to the class library project.

Edit: Use a traditional class library, not an ASP.Net 5 class library.

Comment: Same problem, I can not add an thiert party element to the ClassLibrary and when I use a ClassLibrary from ASP.NET 4.5 i get a error message

Comment: This technique requires you to use a traditional class library, not an asp.net class library.

Answer (score 1):

(1) [Package your assembly with nuget](https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package)
(2) Follow the @AndersNS [answer talking about nuget repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29368176/add-reference-to-asp-net-5-class-library-from-framework-4-5-class-library-projec/29371954#29371954)